# VNCServer error on arch linux: The HOME environment variable is not set

Tags: linux, arch-linux, vnc, tigervnc

I am using arch linux.

I could not connect VNC server created by gnome.

Then I installed tigervnc, then run `tigervnc` once to initialize

But `systemctl start vncserver` failed:

```
● vncserver.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vncserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-01-16 22:39:59 CST; 4s ago
Process: 17611 ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -fg  (code=exited, status=2)
Process: 17609 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/vncserver -kill  >/dev/null 2>&1 || true (code=exit
Main PID: 17611 (code=exited, status=2)

1月 16 22:39:59 bjpc systemd[1]: Starting Remote desktop service (VNC)...
1月 16 22:39:59 bjpc systemd[1]: Started Remote desktop service (VNC).
1月 16 22:39:59 bjpc vncserver[17611]: vncserver: The HOME environment variable is not set.
1月 16 22:39:59 bjpc systemd[1]: vncserver.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALI
1月 16 22:39:59 bjpc systemd[1]: vncserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Then I installed `x11vnc`, and the same error occured.

Answer (score -1):

Don't mess around with this service. Vncserver will work well after creating your server-session with command

`vncserver`

black screen issue with vnc often is a results of wrong configuration in

```
$ ~/.vnc/xstartup
```

try running your vncserver with following 
(if using xfce do not use `startxfce4` but `xfce4-session`!)

```
$ ~/.vnc/xstartup

    #!/bin/sh

    exec dbus-launch gnome-session
```

This is also a possible solution if you are getting checkbox ,,unable to contact settings server"